# Can other websites harvest questions asked on SO and display them as if it were their own?

Tags: discussion, legal

This sounds like someone is trying to build their own Q&A site by ripping off questions and answers from SO. Is that allowed?

See here: http://w3facility.org/question/xacml-on-android/

The original SO question is [XACML on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605403/xacml-on-android)

Comment: The [CC license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) on all Stack Overflow content allows other sites to re-post the content, *provided* they attribute the content correctly. The site you linked to appears to do so.

Comment: It only links back to the original question though @MartijnPieters. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it should also directly link back to the original authors.

Comment: @Bart: I didn't check thoroughly; I saw author links and a link to the post, so I used the term 'apparently'. *Apparently* they are not in *full* compliance then. :-)

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would downvote my question. It seemed valid enough

Comment: this one is missing a link back to SO: http://w3facility.org/question/what%2ddoes%2d__attribute____interrupt__%2dno_auto_psv-do/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sites are allowed to take the content from Stack Overflow (or any site in the SE network for that matter) and re-host it. They are however not allowed to pretend it's their own. The [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license does require proper attribution. So what does this mean. As stated [in this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

> we require that you:
>
> 1. Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a
>    discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> 3. Show the author names for every question and answer
> 4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the
>    source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

The site you have linked to appears to comply with the first 3 points, but doesn't link back to user profiles. That is not appropriate and should be corrected.

Comment: The w3facility site is making ghost "member" accounts on their site and crediting the content to those accounts; those accounts then link back to StackExchange profile.  This is possibly in legal compliance, but not compliant with the spirit of the licensing.  They could possibly lose if sued, and I'd love to see them sued.